# Implementing a U-net for image segmentation and have the following error: NameError: name 'val_iou' is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use a U-net to apply image segmentation to the RUGD dataset.  I get the following error, I'm stuck.

```
       'lrs':lrs}

print('Total time: {:.2f}m' .format((time.time()-fit_time)/60))

return history

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-112aada9db24> in <module>
         98 
         99         #iou
    --> 100 val_iou.append(val_iou_score/len(val_loader))
        101 train_iou.append(iou_score/len(train_loader))
        102 train_acc.append(accuracy/len(train_loader))

    NameError: name 'val_iou' is not defined
```

Installing segmentation-models for pytorch

```
!pip install -q segmentation-models-pytorch
!pip install -q torchsummary
```

Installing Libraries

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms as T
import torchvision
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable


from PIL import Image
import cv2
import albumentations as A

import os
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

from torchsummary import summary
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp

device = torch.device("cpu" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Name and direct paths

```
IMAGE_PATH = '/data/users/mypath/Rugd_dataset/images/train/'
MASK_PATH = '/data/users/mypath/Rugd_dataset/mask/train/'
```

Create dataframe

```
n_classes = 24

def create_df():
    name = []
    for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk(IMAGE_PATH):
        for filename in filenames:
            name.append(filename.split('.')[0])
    return pd.DataFrame({'id': name}, index = np.arange(0, len(name)))

df = create_df()
print('Total Images: ',len(df))
```

Total Images:  7387

Split Test and Train

```
X_trainval, X_test = train_test_split(df['id'].values, test_size=0.1, random_state=19)
X_train, X_val = train_test_split(X_trainval, test_size=0.15, random_state=19)

print('Train Size : ', len(X_train))
print('Val Size : ', len(X_val))
print('Test Size : ', len(X_test))


# show original picture with overlay of mask

img = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH + df['id'][0] + '.png')
mask = Image.open(MASK_PATH + df['id'][0] + '.png')
print('Image size', np.asarray(img).shape)
print('Mask size', np.asarray(mask).shape)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(mask, alpha=0.6)
plt.title('Picture with Mask Applied')
plt.show()
```

Image size (550, 688, 3)
Mask size (550, 688, 3)

[image rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6rgv.png)

Define U-net

```
class RugdDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, img_path, mask_path, X, mean, std, transform=None, patch=False):
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.mask_path = mask_path
        self.X = X
        self.transform = transform
        self.patches = patch
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = cv2.imread(self.img_path + self.X[idx] + '.png')
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        mask = cv2.imread(self.mask_path + self.X[idx] + '.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    
        if self.transform is not None:
            aug = self.transform(image=img, mask=mask)
            img = Image.fromarray(aug['image'])
            mask = aug['mask']
        
        if self.transform is None:
            img = Image.fromarray(img)
        
        t = T.Compose([T.ToTensor(), T.Normalize(self.mean, self.std)])
        img = t(img)
        mask = torch.from_numpy(mask).long()
        
        '''
        if self.patches:
            img, mask = self.tiles(img, mask)
        
        return img, mask
        '''
    '''
    def tiles(self, img, mask):
        img_patches = img.unfold(1, 512, 512).unfold(2, 768, 768)
        im_patches = img_patches.continuous().view(3, -1, 512, 768)
        img_patches = img_patches.permute(1,0,2,3)
        
        mask_patches = mask.unfold(0, 512, 512).unfold(1, 768, 768)
        mask_patches = mask_patches.contiguous().view(-1, 512, 768)
        
        return img_patches, mask_patches
    '''
```

Apply augmentation and initiate dataloader

```
mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

t_train = A.Compose([A.Resize(512, 512, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST), A.HorizontalFlip(), A.VerticalFlip(),
                     A.GridDistortion(p=0.2), A.RandomBrightnessContrast((0,0.5),(0,0.5)), A.GaussNoise()])
t_val = A.Compose([A.Resize(512, 512, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST), A.HorizontalFlip(), A.GridDistortion(p=0.2)])

# dataset
train_set = RugdDataset(IMAGE_PATH, MASK_PATH, X_train, mean, std, t_train, patch=False)
val_set = RugdDataset(IMAGE_PATH, MASK_PATH, X_val, mean, std, t_val, patch=False)

# dataloader
batch_size = 3

train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

build the model

```
model = smp.Unet('mobilenet_v2', encoder_weights='imagenet', classes=24, activation=None,
                 encoder_depth=5, decoder_channels=[256, 128, 64, 32, 16])
```

render the model

```
model

Def pixel accuracy

def pixel_accuracy(output, mask):
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = torch.argmax(F.softmax(output, dim=1), dim=1)
        correct = torch.eq(output, mask).int()
        accuracy = float(correct.sum()) / float(correct.numel())
    return accuracy
```

Define Miou

```
def mIoU(pred_mask, mask, smooth=1e-10, n_classes=24):
    with torch.no_grad():
        pred_mask = F.softmax(pred_mask, dim=1)
        pred_mask = torch.argmax(pred_mask, dim=1)
        pred_mask = pred_mask.contiguous().view(-1)
        mask = mask.contiguous().view(-1)
        
        iou_per_class = []
        for clas in range(0, n_classes): #loop per pixel class
            true_class = pred_mask == clas
            true_label = mask == clas
            
            if true_label.long().sum().item() == 0: # no exist label in this loop
                iou_per_class.append(np.nan)
            else:
                intersect = torch.logical_and(true_class, true_label).sum().float().item()
                union = torch.logical_or(true_class, true_label).sum().float().item()
                
                iou = (intersect + smooth) / (union + smooth)
                iou_per_class.append(iou)
        return np.nanmean(iou_per_class)
```

def get_lr(optimizer):
for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
return param_group['lr']

```
def fit(epochs, model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, patch=False):
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    train_losses = []
    test_losses = []
    val_iou = []; val_acc = []
    train_iou = []; train_acc = []
    lrs = []
    min_loss = np.inf
    decrease = 1 ; not_improve=0
    
    model.to(device)
    fit_time = time.time()
    for e in range(epochs):
        since = time.time()
        running_loss = 0
        iou_score = 0
        accuracy = 0
        # training loop
        model.train()
        '''
        for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
            # training phase
            image_tiles, mask_tiles = data
            if patch:
                bs, n_tiles, c, h, w = image_tiles.size()
                
                image_tiles = image_tiles.view(-1,c, h, w)
                mask_tiles = mask_tiles.view(-1, h, w)
        '''
                
        image = img.to(device); mask = mask.to(device);
            
            # forward
        output = model(image)
        loss = criterion(output, mask)
            # evaluation metrics
        iou_score += mIoU(output, mask)
        accuracy += pixel_accuracy(output, mask)
            # backward
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() #update weight
        optimizer.zero_grad() #reset gradient
            
            # step the learining rate
        lrs.append(get_lr(optimizer))
        scheduler.step()
            
        running_loss += loss.item()
        
    else:
        model.eval()
        test_loss = 0
        test_accuracy = 0
        val_iou_score = 0
        # validation loop
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(val_loader)):
                # reshape to 9 patches 
                image, mask = data

                if patch:
                    bs, n, c, h, w = image.size()

                    image = image.view(-1, c, h, w)
                    mask = mask.view(-1, h, w)

                image = img.to(device); mask = mask.to(device);
                output = model(image)
                # evaluation metrics
                val_iou_score += mIoU(output, mask)
                test_accuracy += pixel_accuracy(output, mask)
                # loss
                loss = criterion(output, mask)
                test_loss += loss.item()
                # calculate mean for each batch
            train_losses.append(running_loss/len(train_loader))
            test_losses.append(test_loss/len(val_loader))

            if min_loss > (test_loss/len(val_loader)):
                print('Loss Decreasing.. {:.3f} >> {:.3f} ' .format(min_loss, (test_loss/len(val_loader))))
                min_loss = (test_loss/len(val_loader))
                decrease += 1
                if decrease % 5 == 0:
                    print('saving model...')
                    torch.save(model, 'Unet-mobilnet_v2_mIoU-{:.3f}.pt'.format(val_iou_score/len(val_loader)))

            if (test_loss/len(val_loader)) > min_loss:
                not_improve += 1
                min_loss = (test_loss/len(val_loader))
                print(f'Loss Not Decrease for {not_improve} time')
                if not_improve == 7:
                    print('Loss not decrease for 7 times, Stop Training')
                    # break

#iou
val_iou.append(val_iou_score/len(val_loader))
train_iou.append(iou_score/len(train_loader))
train_acc.append(accuracy/len(train_loader))
val_acc.append(test_accuracy/len(val_loader))
print("Epoch:{}/{}".format(e+1, epochs),
      "Train Loss: {:.3f}..".format(running_loss/len(train_loader)),
      "Val Loss: {:.3f}..".format(test_loss/len(val_loader)),
      "Train mIoU:{:.3f}..".format(iou_score/len(train_loader)),
      "Val mIoU:{:.3f}..".format(val_iou_score/len(val_loader)),
      "Val ACC:{:.3f}..".format(test_accuracy/len(val_loader)),
      "Time: {:.2f}m".format((time.time()-since)/60))

history = {'train_loss' : train_losses, 'val_loss': test_losses,
           'train_miou' : train_iou, 'val_miou':val_iou,
           'train_acc' :train_acc, 'val_acc':val_acc,
           'lrs':lrs}
print('Total time: {:.2f}m' .format((time.time()-fit_time)/60))
return history
```

This the point where the model fails

```
         'lrs':lrs}

print('Total time: {:.2f}m' .format((time.time()-fit_time)/60))

return history

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-112aada9db24> in <module>
         98 
         99         #iou
    --> 100 val_iou.append(val_iou_score/len(val_loader))
        101 train_iou.append(iou_score/len(train_loader))
        102 train_acc.append(accuracy/len(train_loader))
    
    NameError: name 'val_iou' is not defined
```

Remainder of the code

```
max_lr = 1e-3
epoch = 15
weight_decay = 1e-4

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=max_lr, weight_decay=weight_decay)
sched = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(optimizer, max_lr, epochs=epoch, steps_per_epoch=len(train_loader))

history = fit(epoch, model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, sched)
```

Comment: in python, indentation is syntax. why do you expect that variable to exist at that point in the code?

Comment: Christoph. did you see an indention error

Comment: look over your question. simply pasting code won't format it properly. you need to put code tags `\`\`\`` around it or use the `<>` *button* while the code is selected. -- there's an entire piece of code, ending in `return history`, indented to suggest that it's *not* part of a function but supposed to be in the global scope.

Comment: unfortunately not.  Whats your recommendation

Comment: my recommendation is to try again to copy that code from wherever you got it. indentation is messed up. -- if that doesn't help, you'll want to learn about python *debugging*. learn what `NameError: name 'some_variable' is not defined` *means*. that's fundamental stuff. I'm here for interesting problems, not for teaching fundamentals. sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NameError%3A+name+is+not+defined